# Multiple pluralisable variables in internationalized django template

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I am internationalizing (i18n) our django project, i.e. adding `{% blocktrans %}` to our templates. I know about using `count` and `{% plural %}` to have different strings for varaibles. However I have a string that has two variables that each need to be pluralized, i.e. 4 possible options.

For example, my string is `"You have {{ num_unread }} unread message{{ num_unread|pluralize }} out of  {{ total }} total message{{ total|pluralize }}"`

How would I convert that to `blocktrans` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research and reading, specifically about gettext, I don't think this is possible. gettext documentation only allows one variable to control the pluralization. There are probably problems with having 2 variable pluralization, since in arabic, you'd have to have 36 different strings to translate.

In the end I just worked around my original problem, and split it into two strings.